# Pandas: Need to find # of unique names over both columns

Tags: pandas, unique

I have this textfile right here:

```
node1    node2   
desmond jaski  
desmond kulwant  
desmond monty  
desmond bobby  
jaski gunny  
jaski jonny  
david jaski   
david kulwant          
gursh jassi  
arsh gunny   
arsh jaski  
arsh jassi  
sunny jassi  
billy bobby  
billy gill  
numan jassi
```

I need to find how many unique names are in both of these columns together. The answer should be 15 names between the 2 columns but I dont know how to get this. I can only get the unique names in each column.

Comment: stack / melt + drop_duplicates

Comment: `df.groupby(['node1', 'node2']).size().sum()`

Comment: Wow my brain doesn't want to work today. Thank you.

Comment: or `df['node1'].str.cat(df['node2']).nunique()`

Comment: Wait, this is a very confusing example. There are both 16 unique names considering both rows `df.drop_duplicates()` and 16 unique values across both rows: `df.stack().drop_duplicates()`. Can you add an example that distinguishes between the two.

Comment: I changed it so now there are 15 unique names. stacking and dropping duplicates gets this result.     

nodes = df.stack().drop_duplicates().count()